# Rails + Carrierwave + RMagick : Crop only if image is large

Tags: ruby, carrierwave, rmagick

I am using carrier-wave to upload images. On upload I am creating thumbnails for the image which is done using Rmagick method, resize_to_fill like below.

```
version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill=> [150, 150]
end
```

Here is output of all the RMagick methods carrierwave [supports](http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/) (none of which I want):

1. `:resize_to_fill => [150,150]`

**This works fine on larger images but my smaller images are enlarged to 150 x 150.**
[image: :resize_to_fill => [150,150]]

2. `:resize_to_fit => [150,150]`

**Again it was resized, I want it left alone!**

[image: :resize_to_fit => [150,150]]

3. `:resize_to_limit => [150,150]`

**This one leaves it as is, but larger images are not cropped. They are resized to keep the aspect ratio.**

[image]

[image]

**Here is the result I want and how my small and larger images should look.**

[image]
[image]

How do this? I want smaller images to be left alone and crop only larger images to 150 x 150. Is there another method or options I can pass to resize_to_fill?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it by modifying `:resize_to_fill` carrierwave method as described in their code [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb#L188).

I just made a new method with the same code with a check to see if the uploaded image is smaller. Here is the new method:

```
def resize_to_fill_modfied(width, height, gravity=::Magick::CenterGravity)
      manipulate! do |img|
        img.crop_resized!(width, height, gravity) unless (img.columns <= width && img.rows <= height)
        img = yield(img) if block_given?
        img
      end
    end
```

Does exactly what I want now.